# Reffering environment based scripts in index.html in React project

Tags: javascript, reactjs, webpack

I am trying to use custom scripts file on **index.html** file in react project. I can't directly refer it as its environment based. So for dev environment, I want to use **customFunc.dev.js** in my index.html file and for prod environment, I want to use customFunc.test.js. Can we insert script tags dynamically through webpack configuration?

Below is the webpack configuration I am using to serve bundle.js from a public folder where my **index.html** is residing.

```
var webpack = require('webpack');
        var path = require('path');

        module.exports = {
           context : path.resolve('src'),
           entry: ["babel-polyfill", './index.js'],

            output: {
                path : path.resolve('build/js'),
                filename: 'bundle.js',
                publicPath : '/public/assets/js/'
            },
             externals: {
              'Config': JSON.stringify(require("./config.prod.json"))
             },
            devServer: {
            historyApiFallback: true,
            disableHostCheck: true,
            contentBase : 'public'
        }
    }
```

### Index.html

```
<!doctype html>
<html lang="en">
  <head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
    <meta name="description">
    <title>Demo Project</title>
  </head>
  <body>
    <div id="appContainer"></div>
      <script  type="text/javascript" src="/public/assets/js/bundle.js"></script>
  </body>
</html>
```

I want to inject my custom script file into **index.html** page. I am somewhat new to **webpack**. Any help would be much appreciated.